# not able to load external jar in aws lamda

Tags: spring, aws-lambda, pom.xml, boot

i am creating service in spring boot and i want to deploy it in lamda . i have few dependency in lib folder .

```
02/24/2023  10:52 AM    <DIR>          .
02/24/2023  10:52 AM    <DIR>          ..
02/24/2023  10:52 AM           118,397 PaymentechSDK_7.4.jar
02/24/2023  10:52 AM         6,347,540 PayPalAPIInterfaceService-test-client.jar
02/24/2023  10:52 AM         4,015,472 PayPal_stub.jar
02/24/2023  10:52 AM            89,343 sunrsasign.jar
```

which is working in my local correctly but when i try to deploy it in lambda. I am getting error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267)
    ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
   com/paymentech/orbital/sdk/util/exceptions/InitializationException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2729)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2003)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
    ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    com.paymentech.orbital.sdk.util.exceptions.InitializationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 29 more
```

can anyone suggest an method to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies must be placed in a [Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html).

Here's a [sample application for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/main/sample-apps/blank-java).